# React: setState is not defined, I already tried binding this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a very simple React Login Page:

```
import React from "react";
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

export default class Login extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.handleEmail = this.handleEmail.bind(this);
    this.handlePW = this.handlePW.bind(this);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      pw: "",
    }
  }

  handleEmail(event){
    this.setState({email:event.target.value});
    console.log(setState);
  }

  handlePW(event){
    this.setState({pw:event.target.value});
    console.log(setState);
  }

  handleLogin(){
    console.log("clicked");
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <form>
          Email:
          <br/>
          <input type="text" id="email" onChange={this.handleEmail}/>
          <br/>
          PW:
          <br/>
          <input type="text" id="pw" onChange={this.handlePW}/>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick={this.handleLogin}/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I'm running into the following error: "ReferenceError: setState is not defined"

The goal is for me to assign the value of Email and Password on Submit button click. I read some other StackOverflow questions and it appears that the issue was the this binding—I tried to address this in the Constructor. What is causing this error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I'm getting a "ReferenceError: setState is not defined" error but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: I think the state is being set just fine, the error comes from the console log statement, you are missing a "this" there

Comment: `console.log(setState);` is creating the error.  Replace it with the code I mention in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to log your state to the console, you should use `console.log(this.state)`.